# systemd service: Is it possible to get the name of the user who triggered a power event?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, init

I'm trying to modify the power-related service files that come with systemd (for example, `systemd-reboot.service`) so that they run another command before bringing down the system. I want this command to have access to the name of the user that triggered the power event. Is this possible through any standard means?

I thought that `systemctl` might simply pass the user's environment to the service, but it seems that it only makes available one or two select variables, unless you manually run `systemctl set-environment` or `systemctl import-environment` to add to them... which i can't expect consumers of the service to do.

I'm also aware of template files, and i think they would be useful here, but as far as i understand it (?) the invocation of these particular service files is hard-coded into systemd, so i think i'm limited to making changes that won't break the 'API' it's using.

My system is running Ubuntu 16.04.2 with systemd 229.